# AngularJs + ES6: Error in performing member actions

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I am using AngularJs 1.5.3 with ES6. I am trying to perform CRUD operations where user can update, delete or edit the stripe cards. Create and Delete methods are working fine. The problem I am facing occurs when I try to render the `edit` form.

Following is the route defined for edit action:

**Route**

```
.state('account.edit', {
  templateUrl: 'app/templates/accounts/edit-card.html',
  controller: 'AccountController',
  url: '/account/edit/{card_id}',
  controllerAs: 'account',
  resolve: {
    data: (CardResource, $auth, $state) => {
      'ngInject'
      return $auth.validateToken()
      .then(() => => CardResource.get({id: $stateParams["card_id"]}).$promise)
      .catch((e) => console.log(e) )
    },
    action: () => 'edit'
  }
})
```

Here is my Edit action in accounts controller

```
edit() {
  const {
    data: { name, expire_date, address_zip }
  } = this;
  this.cardParams = {
    name,
    address_zip, 
    expire_date
  }
```

}

And here is my view code `card.jade` where I am passing the_card id to edit action:

```
a(ui-sref="account.edit({card_id: card.id}))")
      i.fa.fa-edit
```

**Updated**

Factory class code

```
export function CardResourceFactory($resource)
{
  'ngInject';
   return $resource('/api/cards/:id', null, {
   });
}
```

`ui-serf` is creating correct url e.g `#/account/edit/card_xxxxxxxx`. But when i click on `edit` icon it should change the url and render the template mention in `Route` but nothing happens. Surely I am missing something here. Can anyone help?

Comment: No errors? "Nothing happens" doesnt really help.

Comment: thanks @CristianS. for reply. Yes exactly it does not show any errors as well doesn't renders the edit form.

Comment: What is the expected link after the user clicks the edit button? In the promise part do `.catch((e) => console.log(e))`

Comment: Expected link is `#/account/edit/card_xxxxxxxx. `  i believe on edit button click state is not changing or if it is changing either it could not find the "state" to redirect.

Comment: I tried  `.catch((e) => console.log(e))` it prints nothing on console. meaning promise part is working correctly. am i right?

Comment: If there is no error caught then the promise its resolving as it should be. Do you get any HTML output in the white page?

Comment: Nope. No HTML output on page

Comment: Well its pretty hard to know whats going on just with the piece of code from OP. You will need to debug step by step checking if the template path is correct if the data is being passed correctly, etc..

Comment: Okay thank you much for giving your precious time. Actually i am newbie to angular and i don't know how to debug Angular code. Do you know something about it any link or info would be helpful. thanks

Comment: @CristianS. I have added some more piece of code. Please have a look at it . May be you can find something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168728/discussion-between-cristian-s-and-talha-junaid).